# Implicit conversion of UUID to character varying when using TEIID with postgres

Tags: postgresql, uuid, teiid

I have a VDB containing a view with a UUID column with this definition

```
<vdb name="_GENERATED_users_info" version="6">
    <import-vdb name="_INTERNAL_internal" version="1"/>
    <model name="GEN_view" type="VIRTUAL">
        <metadata type="DDL">
            <![CDATA[ CREATE VIEW "_view_workflow_data" ("uuid" VARCHAR, "email" VARCHAR) OPTIONS (UPDATABLE 'true') AS SELECT "public"."security_users_info"."uuid" AS "uuid", "public"."security_users_info"."email" AS "email" FROM "public"."security_users_info" ]]></metadata>
    </model>
</vdb>
```

Column `security_users_info.uuid` is of type `UUID`.
When I try to execute a query
`SELECT "uuid", "email" FROM "_view_workflow_data" WHERE ("uuid" IN (?''718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7') AND 1 = 1)`
I get an error **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying**. The error doesn't come from the query I sent but from a query generated by TEIID executed on the physical table

`TEIID11004 Error executing statement(s): [Prepared Values: ['718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7'] SQL: SELECT cast(g_0."uuid" AS varchar), g_0."email" FROM "public"."security_users_info" AS g_0 WHERE g_0."uuid" = ?]`

I tried to convert the column in the view definition to varchar like this `CONVERT("public"."security_users_info"."uuid", VARCHAR)  AS "uuid"` but I get the same error.

The failing query works fine directly in postgresql as it implicitly converts the uuid text into a uuid type.

I'm aware of the section about UID types in http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/as_jdbc-translators.html but as the implicit conversion seems to work when I execute the query directly in postgresql, I would expect that section not to apply in this situation.

I'm using TEIID 16 with postgresql 9.5 and postgres JDBC driver 42.2.

Am I doing something in a wrong way or is this not supposed to work?

Whole stacktrace:

```
ERROR# - org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select "uuid", "email" from "_view_workflow_data" where ("uuid" in (?) and 1 = 1)]; TEIID30504 Remote org.teiid.core.TeiidProcessingException: TEIID30504 _SOURCE_7772c4bdad42f2468b3ecdc71d89634bd9b80ff2ca87900862ab740105049694: 0 TEIID11008:TEIID11004 Error executing statement(s): [Prepared Values: ['718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7'] SQL: SELECT cast(g_0."uuid" AS varchar), g_0."email" FROM "public"."security_users_info" AS g_0 WHERE g_0."uuid" = ?] (c.m.w.c.d.DataObjectVerticle#?)org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select "uuid", "email" from "_view_workflow_data" where ("uuid" in (?) and 1 = 1)]; TEIID30504 Remote org.teiid.core.TeiidProcessingException: TEIID30504 _SOURCE_7772c4bdad42f2468b3ecdc71d89634bd9b80ff2ca87900862ab740105049694: 0 TEIID11008:TEIID11004 Error executing statement(s): [Prepared Values: ['718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7'] SQL: SELECT cast(g_0."uuid" AS varchar), g_0."email" FROM "public"."security_users_info" AS g_0 WHERE g_0."uuid" = ?]
    at org.jooq_3.13.0-SNAPSHOT.DEFAULT.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2717)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:755)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:382)
    at com.mathesio.workflow.core.dataObject.DataObjectService.lambda$select$16(DataObjectService.java:365)
    at com.mathesio.teiid.Connections.ConnectionManager.lambda$getConnectionJOOQ$0(ConnectionManager.java:187)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext$3.run(DefaultDSLContext.java:609)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext$3.run(DefaultDSLContext.java:606)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.lambda$transactionResult0$0(DefaultDSLContext.java:537)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools$12$1.block(Tools.java:4847)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3128)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools$12.get(Tools.java:4844)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.transactionResult0(DefaultDSLContext.java:589)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.transactionResult(DefaultDSLContext.java:506)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.transaction(DefaultDSLContext.java:606)
    at com.mathesio.teiid.Connections.ConnectionManager.lambda$getConnectionJOOQ$1(ConnectionManager.java:186)
    at com.mathesio.workflow.core.database.transaction.TransactionJPA.lambda$new$42(TransactionJPA.java:1813)
    at com.mathesio.workflow.core.database.transaction.TransactionJPA.lambda$new$19(TransactionJPA.java:388)
    at com.mathesio.workflow.core.database.transaction.TransactionJPA.runCore(TransactionJPA.java:993)
    at com.mathesio.workflow.core.database.transaction.TransactionJPA.lambda$run$25(TransactionJPA.java:1306)
    at com.mathesio.workflow.core.database.transaction.TransactionJPA$1.call(TransactionJPA.java:755)
    at com.mathesio.workflow.core.database.transaction.TransactionJPA$1.call(TransactionJPA.java:738)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.mathesio.workflow.core.database.transaction.PriorityFuture.run(PriorityFuture.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException: TEIID30504 Remote org.teiid.core.TeiidProcessingException: TEIID30504 _SOURCE_7772c4bdad42f2468b3ecdc71d89634bd9b80ff2ca87900862ab740105049694: 0 TEIID11008:TEIID11004 Error executing statement(s): [Prepared Values: ['718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7'] SQL: SELECT cast(g_0."uuid" AS varchar), g_0."email" FROM "public"."security_users_info" AS g_0 WHERE g_0."uuid" = ?]
    at org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException.create(TeiidSQLException.java:131)
    at org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException.create(TeiidSQLException.java:67)
    at org.teiid.jdbc.StatementImpl.postReceiveResults(StatementImpl.java:783)
    at org.teiid.jdbc.StatementImpl.access$100(StatementImpl.java:62)
    at org.teiid.jdbc.StatementImpl$2.onCompletion(StatementImpl.java:581)
    at org.teiid.client.util.ResultsFuture.done(ResultsFuture.java:131)
    at org.teiid.client.util.ResultsFuture.access$200(ResultsFuture.java:36)
    at org.teiid.client.util.ResultsFuture$1.receiveResults(ResultsFuture.java:75)
    at org.teiid.net.socket.SocketServerInstanceImpl.receivedMessage(SocketServerInstanceImpl.java:281)
    at org.teiid.net.socket.SocketServerInstanceImpl.read(SocketServerInstanceImpl.java:333)
    at org.teiid.net.socket.SocketServerInstanceImpl$RemoteInvocationHandler$1.get(SocketServerInstanceImpl.java:423)
    at org.teiid.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeSql(StatementImpl.java:590)
    at org.teiid.jdbc.PreparedStatementImpl.execute(PreparedStatementImpl.java:240)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:3935)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:294)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:368)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.teiid.core.TeiidProcessingException: TEIID30504 Remote org.teiid.core.TeiidProcessingException: TEIID30504 _SOURCE_7772c4bdad42f2468b3ecdc71d89634bd9b80ff2ca87900862ab740105049694: 0 TEIID11008:TEIID11004 Error executing statement(s): [Prepared Values: ['718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7'] SQL: SELECT cast(g_0."uuid" AS varchar), g_0."email" FROM "public"."security_users_info" AS g_0 WHERE g_0."uuid" = ?]
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.exceptionOccurred(DataTierTupleSource.java:397)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.nextTuple(DataTierTupleSource.java:157)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.query.processor.relational.AccessNode.nextBatchDirect(AccessNode.java:401)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalNode.nextBatch(RelationalNode.java:277)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.query.processor.relational.RelationalPlan.nextBatch(RelationalPlan.java:139)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatchDirect(QueryProcessor.java:147)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.query.processor.QueryProcessor.nextBatch(QueryProcessor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:160)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.query.processor.BatchCollector.collectTuples(BatchCollector.java:142)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.processMore(RequestWorkItem.java:491)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.process(RequestWorkItem.java:361)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.AbstractWorkItem.run(AbstractWorkItem.java:43)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.RequestWorkItem.run(RequestWorkItem.java:284)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DQPWorkContext.runInContext(DQPWorkContext.java:283)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:124)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$2.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:212)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.teiid.translator.TranslatorException: 0 Remote org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionException: 0 TEIID11008:TEIID11004 Error executing statement(s): [Prepared Values: ['718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7'] SQL: SELECT cast(g_0."uuid" AS varchar), g_0."email" FROM "public"."security_users_info" AS g_0 WHERE g_0."uuid" = ?]
    at org.jboss.teiid.translator.jdbc@16.0.0//org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCQueryExecution.execute(JDBCQueryExecution.java:127)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorWorkItem.execute(ConnectorWorkItem.java:405)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorManager$1.invoke(ConnectorManager.java:228)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.getResults(DataTierTupleSource.java:302)
    at org.jboss.teiid@16.0.0//org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.nextTuple(DataTierTupleSource.java:138)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Remote org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 109
    at org.postgresql@42.2.2//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.2//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.2//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.2//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.2//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.2//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at org.postgresql@42.2.2//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at org.jboss.teiid.translator.jdbc@16.0.0//org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCQueryExecution.execute(JDBCQueryExecution.java:119)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I have no idea about TEIID, but it seems a casting is necessary. You be much better off reversing the cast. I.E. do not case the database column from UUID to a string, instead cast the string value to a UUID. This leaves any index on that column functional while casting the database column nullifies any index.  Strainge Postgres this becomes "WHERE "uuid" IN (718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7'::uuid" or "WHERE  "uuid"  cast ('718e52dd-058a-4306-9213-c999181163c7' AS uuid")

Comment: I don't think that is possible. TEIID queries don't know the type UUID, as stated in the documentation link in the OP , UID types are mapped to a string type.
I tried to add the cast and ended up with an expected error `TEIID31254 Datatype or domain uuid is not known.`

Comment: Sorry it did not help, but as I said I do not know TEIID. It is also why I dislike obfuscation layers (in this case TEIID). They often (usually) fail to fully support database capabilities they claim to support. Postgres has supported uuid as a data type since at least 8.3 (EOL Feb 2013)